# rally svnToRally connector -> RallyBaseUrl gets modified with slm suffix, how to fix that?

Tags: rally

Tryint to run config-rally.rb and checked in the error log file that rallybaseurl gets modified with slm suffix. slm suffix has not been provided in config.xml, so what's modifying that property?

Can anyone throw some light on this property value change as it's causing rally workspace error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix by modifying the scm_config_reader.rb script

Comment: This was needed for Rally-SSO integration.